# Can't run a VS Universal Windows App project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I'm very new to Visual Studio and *Universal Windows Apps Development*. As a part of the course, I have this [codeSHOW project](https://github.com/codefoster/codeshow) provided.

I've cloned it successfully in **VS 2015**, but I can't run the project using the .sln file. Error:

[image]

Here's the error log: http://pastebin.com/c012Bba4

I have no clue how to fix it, and the issues on github go unanswered so I can't expect much from there.

Comment: @Jeroen Ohk, its VS 2015 on Windows 10. What other details can I provide? Sorry, I'm very new to this so not sure how it all works in Win environment.

Comment: @Jeroen I've updated the description with version and the error log.

Comment: Why negative vote? Atleast explain ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a VS2015 specific bug, the solution loads just fine on VS2013.  You can get *some* insight into what is going wrong.  First note that your got **two** message boxes that announced this error.  Barely visible in your screenshot.

The failure.txt file gives more hints, you can see the stack traces of the two AggregateException that are raised when the solution is loaded.  You'll see that *two* tasks are trying to load the same resources.resjon project item.  Not correct of course, quacks like a standard concurrency bug.

Nothing *actually* goes wrong, Visual Studio can handle the exception and declares it "Recoverable", the projects are still loaded correctly.  And compile just fine.  Only other thing you need is the Bing Maps SDK, you can download the correct version [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/224eb93a-ebc4-46ba-9be7-90ee777ad9e1).

If you have VS2013 then prefer that version, it doesn't have this bug and loads the solution without any complaint.  And minimizes the odds that you'll run into other quirky problems.  Given the current stability of VS2015, not great, it is the best way to avoid losing time.  Otherwise just ignore the mishap and close the message boxes, some future Update will no doubt fix the bug.  You can report it at connect.microsoft.com if you wish.  Not actually necessary I think, it looks like VS is phoning home.

Comment: Ah! I'm actually preparing for *MCSD: Windows Store Apps* certification. The "developer apps in HTML, CSS and JS" caught my eye and indeed its that way but I didn't think learning VS would be such a huge learning curve. Thanks for the detailed answer, I'll get VS 2013. I thought VS2015 was ready for prime time since it launched for public just a few days ago, but well. I just hope there aren't too many differences and hope they don't ask VS 2015 specific questions in the exam,

Comment: I installed VS 2013 and it indeed runs fine. Thanks heaps, I'd have not figured it out on my own!

Answer (score 2):

This is an known issue in Visual Studio 2015.
The problem is with files with the exact same name under different folders in a Shared project, which in your case is "resources.resjson".

The only workarounds are either to make the file names unique and if that is not an option, to duplicate the files in the projects instead of sharing them out of the Shared project.